# Understanding the "least normal subgroup" in Seifert van Kampen

Tags: algebraic-topology

The Seifert van Kampen theorem implies that if $V$ is simply connected then there is an isomorphism $k: \pi_1(U, x_0) / N \rightarrow \pi(X, x_0)$ where $N$ is the least normal subgroup of $\pi_1(U, x_0)$ containing the image of the homomorphism $i_1: \pi_1(U \cap V, x_0) \rightarrow \pi_1(U, x_0)$ (Munkres).  Can you explain how to actually find this least normal subgroup?

For instance, take the polygon $aabbcc$.  In this case, I'm trying to figure out if $N$ is generated by the loops on each edge, (i.e., $<a, b, c | a^2, b^2, c^2>$) or by the loop $a^2b^2c^2$.  Also in general, suppose you have a polygon like $ab^{-1}ab$.  How would you find the normal subgroup $N$?  Would it be the loop $a^2$?  It seems like it is easy to compute these just by allowing the product to commute, but in terms of the actual theorem, could someone explain how to find these (i.e., using loops in the fundamental group $\pi_1(U \cap V, x_0)$)?  Thank you!

Comment: did you already see the examples when $\pi_1(U\cap V,x_0)$ is trivial?

Comment: No.  Usually I take $V$ to be a disk inside the polygon and $U$ to be $X - \{x\}$ for a point inside $V$. Then $U \cap V$ is not-trivial.  Is there any particular reason why you would take $U \cap V$ to be trivial?  All examples are good because I'm just conceptually struggling with this theorem at this point.

Comment: Really I'm just looking for examples for intuition about calculation methods. I have a final next week and this last section is giving me problems.